# PHP Push simple array values in multidimensional array not working

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-push

**EDIT: UPDATED CODE. PLEASE SEE COMMENTED LINES:**

This is my problem:

I have 2 arrays:

```
$numbers = array(0,3,8);

$data = array('January' => array('BATH' => array('ID', 'user', 'type'), 'KITCHEN' => array('ID', 'user', 'type')), 'february' => array('BATH' => array('ID', 'user', 'type'), 'KITCHEN' => array('ID', 'user', 'type')), 'march' => array('BATH' => array('ID', 'user', 'type'), 'KITCHEN' => array('ID', 'user', 'type')));
```

Expected output must be:

```
array (size=6)
  'January' => 
    array (size=2)
      'BATH' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'ID' (length=2)
          1 => string 'user' (length=4)
          2 => string 'type' (length=4)
      'KITCHEN' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'ID' (length=2)
          1 => string 'user' (length=4)
          2 => string 'type' (length=4)
      'total_lunar' => int '0' // // This is the first value from first array
  'february' => 
    array (size=2)
      'BATH' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'ID' (length=2)
          1 => string 'user' (length=4)
          2 => string 'type' (length=4)
      'KITCHEN' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'ID' (length=2)
          1 => string 'user' (length=4)
          2 => string 'type' (length=4)
       'total_lunar' => int '3' // This is the second value from first array
  'march' => 
    array (size=2)
      'BATH' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'ID' (length=2)
          1 => string 'user' (length=4)
          2 => string 'type' (length=4)
      'KITCHEN' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'ID' (length=2)
          1 => string 'user' (length=4)
          2 => string 'type' (length=4)
       'total_lunar' => int '8' // This is the last value from first array
```

My PHP code is:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($numbers); $i++) 
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) 
    {
        $data[$key]['total_lunar'][$i] =  $numbers[$i];
    }
}
```

I don't know why, the result sets each array but not each value of first array:

```
array (size=6)
  'January' => 
    array (size=2)
      'BATH' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'ID' (length=2)
          1 => string 'user' (length=4)
          2 => string 'type' (length=4)
      'KITCHEN' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'ID' (length=2)
          1 => string 'user' (length=4)
          2 => string 'type' (length=4)
      'total_lunar' => 
          array (size=3)
             0 => int 0
             1 => int 3
             2 => int 8
  'february' => 
    array (size=2)
      'BATH' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'ID' (length=2)
          1 => string 'user' (length=4)
          2 => string 'type' (length=4)
      'KITCHEN' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'ID' (length=2)
          1 => string 'user' (length=4)
          2 => string 'type' (length=4)
       'total_lunar' => 
          array (size=3)
             0 => int 0
             1 => int 3
             2 => int 8
  'march' => 
    array (size=2)
      'BATH' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'ID' (length=2)
          1 => string 'user' (length=4)
          2 => string 'type' (length=4)
      'KITCHEN' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'ID' (length=2)
          1 => string 'user' (length=4)
          2 => string 'type' (length=4)
       'total_lunar' => 
          array (size=3)
             0 => int 0
             1 => int 3
             2 => int 8
```

`['total_lunar']` key should return one value as the expected output above, not all array values. Looked all over for a solution but can't manage to solve this.

Comment: The second level of your `$data` array is the keys `'BATH'` etc. and not a numeric index.

Comment: `$data[$key][$i]` doesn’t exist to push to. Just use `$data[$key][$i] = $numbers[$i];` see the **Note**s at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: You still seem to be having issues with arrays. When in doubt put a `print_r($data[$key]);` in your code an see whats really in the array you are looking at

Comment: `array_push($data[$key]['0'], $numbers[$i]);`

Comment: Updated post. please see.

Comment: NEXT TIME ask a clear question and post only var_export() data and a minimum verifiable example of instead of posting what you got when you tried a solution.

Comment: Yes, thank you for understanding this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple. I think this is what you're looking for?

```
$n=0;
foreach($data as &$d) {
    $d['total_lunar'] = $numbers[$n++];
}
```

The expected output you would se by using this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Updated post. please see.

Comment: So you want an total_lunar key instead of [0]?

Comment: I added it, but it returns me all values from `numbers` array, instead one by one as in my expected output.

Comment: Yes it's functional. Thanks a million times.

Comment: No probem. Glad to help!

Comment: What happened to the *I don't believe you should rely on hard-coded values*?

Comment: @NigelRen - what do you mean?

Comment: I tried myself this before but was missing `&` from `&$d` in `foreach`.

Comment: In the other (now deleted answer) you put that comment for what was effectively the same answer.

Comment: No the deleted answer relied on a specific key to be searched (KITCHEN). That was what I meant by relying on hard-coded...@NigelRen - how is this efffectively the same answer? I don't understand.